# Swift wrapper class

Tags: swift, class, wrapper, swift2

I was watching a talk on swift optimization earlier and they were using an example of a struct with 5 variables 3 strings an array and a dictionary. They said to lower your reference count you could use a wrapper class. Can someone just make a dummy one to I might be able to understand it better.

Comment: Can you share `a talk on swift optimization` to see what exactly you talk about?

Answer (score 2):

A wrapper class would be used if you have performance issues with a struct which has many properties which are reference types.

A generic wrapper class:

```
class Wrapper<T> {
    var value: T // or "let" instead of "var"
    init(_ value: T) { self.value = value }
}
```

This is because if you assign it to another variable all pointers of the properties get copied and therefore all reference counts (see ARC) get incremented (and decremented at the end).

This problem mainly occurs when you are looping over large arrays of such structs where at each iteration a new variable gets created.

With a wrapper class only its reference count gets incremented and decremented once.

Example:

```
struct Big {
    // "n" properties which have reference semantics
    ...
    ...
}

// "m" count
let hugeArray = [Big(), Big(), Big(), ...]

// m * n reference count operations (+1, -1)
for element in hugeArray {
    // do something
}

// if huge array is of type [Wrapper<Big>]
// m * 1 reference count operations (+1, -1)
for element in hugeArray {
    // do something
}
```

Side note: Such a class **could** improve performance. Use it with care if you write to it, assign it or pass it as parameter since it "changes" the semantics of your wrapped type and is no value type.